# Ubuntu server 18.04.1 after installation doesn't boot

Tags: server, 18.04

I've been trying to install ubuntu server 18.04.1 on my notebook hp 620.. all goes fine, I've already set up the IP and similar stuff. After installing it it says installation complete. But when I reboot it, it won't run. 
It either returns Boot error, or it would just go back to boot again from the usb.

**When I booting it up i notice this error:**

```
a. Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-00c629d6....
b. Dependency failed for /subiquity_config.
```

**sudo blkid:**

```
> /dev/sda2: UUID="08b770da-fb32-11e8-92f8-1cc1dea59ea0" TYPE="ext4"
> PARTUUID="126d1f39-80df-426a-996b-806c3570bbea" /dev/sdb1:
> LABEL="LINUX MINT" UUID="006A-911A" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="00f0a883-01"
> /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" /dev/sda1:
> PARTUUID="294d542d-3367-4bc4-a34f-08bbe584eead"
```

**etc/fstab:**

```
UUID=08b770da-fb32-11e8-92f8-1cc1dea59ea0 / ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:84:00.0
       logical name: ens5
       version: 02
       serial: 1c:c1:de:a5:9e:a0
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.238 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:28 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90410000-90410fff memory:90400000-9040ffff memory:90700000-9071ffff
```

**network-manager-all.yaml**

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

**ls -alR /dev/disk**

```
/dev/disk/:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root  140 Dec  9 20:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4240 Dec  9 21:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  220 Dec  9 20:42 by-id
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   60 Dec  9 20:42 by-label
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  100 Dec  9 20:42 by-partuuid
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  160 Dec  9 20:42 by-path
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   80 Dec  9 20:42 by-uuid

/dev/disk/by-id:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 220 Dec  9 20:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 140 Dec  9 20:42 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Dec  9 20:42 ata-Hitachi_HTS545032B9A300_100730PBNC01EYJ404YR -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  9 20:42 ata-Hitachi_HTS545032B9A300_100730PBNC01EYJ404YR-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  9 20:42 ata-Hitachi_HTS545032B9A300_100730PBNC01EYJ404YR-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Dec  9 20:42 ata-hp_CDDVDW_TS-L633N_R3186GMZ625822 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Dec  9 20:42 usb-Samsung_Flash_Drive_0375118070015008-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  9 20:42 usb-Samsung_Flash_Drive_0375118070015008-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Dec  9 20:42 wwn-0x5000cca61ede0117 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  9 20:42 wwn-0x5000cca61ede0117-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  9 20:42 wwn-0x5000cca61ede0117-part2 -> ../../sda2

/dev/disk/by-label:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 Dec  9 20:42  .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 140 Dec  9 20:42  ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  9 20:42 'LINUX\x20MINT' -> ../../sdb1

/dev/disk/by-partuuid:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 100 Dec  9 20:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 140 Dec  9 20:42 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  9 20:42 0210552b-01 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  9 20:42 5d4ec542-3161-412c-8727-a8b7d83295c7 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  9 20:42 81768e13-ad14-4f23-9826-44f23e153d44 -> ../../sda2

/dev/disk/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 160 Dec  9 20:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 140 Dec  9 20:42 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Dec  9 20:42 pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:5:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  9 20:42 pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:5:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Dec  9 20:42 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  9 20:42 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  9 20:42 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Dec  9 20:42 pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-2 -> ../../sr0

/dev/disk/by-uuid:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  80 Dec  9 20:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 140 Dec  9 20:42 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  9 20:42 481c35fc-fbf1-11e8-bd27-1cc1dea59ea0 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  9 20:42 EC28-8E9A -> ../../sdb1
```

Comment: Try changing the drive to use AHCI instead of RAID in the BIOS. That may be the cause of this problem.

Comment: No, it doesnt help, have same problem :/

Comment: can you boot up same hardware using desktop  LiveUSB  ?

Comment: Yes I can, for example Linux Mint 19 working pretty well. I tryed to istall that linux on hdd aswell without having any problems.. Only ubuntu server can't boot up after installation setup..

Comment: Your /etc/fstab has an incorrect UUID for one of your disks. `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and compare UUID's. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema UUID's are the same. Still cant boot. Can't load dhcp while booting.

Comment: Did you configure the .yaml file in /etc/netplan? Try booting into recovery mode, and edit your question with the output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Ping me at @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I dont have any .yaml file in etc netplan.

Comment: @Adainko please see my partial answer, below. Tell me how/wnere you set the server IP.

Comment: @heynnema I doing all from live usb another linux so i found this stuff *see edit*

Comment: I'm confused. Earlier you said there was no .yaml file in /etc/netplan, but now you found one that configures NetworkManager. Are you installing Ubuntu DESKTOP or Ubuntu SERVER? Are you booting from a USB flash drive, or the drive where Ubuntu is installed. Does the Ubuntu drive boot at all? If so, can you get to recovery mode?

Comment: @heynnema I installing ubuntu server 18.04.1. I installing it from usb flash drive. When I get through entire installation it says "installation complete!." Then I simply click on reboot now, but I cant boot it from that hdd. I tryed to format that disk aswell. After installation there was a some stuff on that disk but when i booting from that disk it says No-System disk or disk error.

Comment: I'm out of ideas for now. Please do keep me posted.